# Display SQL Server NULL Value text in Grid View

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, gridview

In the database table certain cells show as NULL, when I create a grid view the string NULL does not show at all, it is just empty for those NULL values. My ultimate goal is to have the grid view look exactly like the db. Note: some columns in the db are of type int not varchar.

For example,

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
Data    NULL    Data
Data    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set [BoundField.NullDisplayText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

i.e.

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="dataField" nulldisplaytext="Null" headertext="Title"/>
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to solve "BoundField is not a known element"?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`BoundField.NullDisplayText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Col2" nulldisplaytext="NULL" headertext="Col2" />
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to solve "BoundField is not a known element"?